# div always sticking to the left border of the page

Tags: javascript, css

I've got a `<div id="mydiv">` with `margin-left: 0px`.
But sometimes (the page is dynamically generated) that this `<div>` is placed within another `<div>` that has a positive margin-left value.
This way `#mydiv` will have the margin of the container and not 0.

Is there a way to set

```
margin-left: 0px (relative to the body margin)
```

or

```
margin-left: -(sum of container margins)?
```

Comment: Can you post your codes and if possible, a rough sketch of what you have now and what you want.

Comment: position: absolute, while looking as the best approach won't work if there are more elements below "mydiv"; they will be shifted up, and so will become hidden by "mydiv" itself.

Comment: absolute won't work. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/salvabalza/Lmtsyd7t/)

Answer (score 1):

If your div is inside another one, the boundaries for that div are limited to it's container div.

You can break out of it by putting `position: absolute;` on the div you want to position differently. Then you should put a `position: relative;` on the container it should be relatively positioned to. Then you can use a negative `margin-left`.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
.mydiv{
  position: absolute;
  left : 0;
}
```

By using an absolute `position` and setting `left` to 0 your `div` will always be aligned with the left side of the containing element with no margin.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS positioning property and align the div's respectively.

> For Example

You have a `<div class="wrapper">` style this with `position:relative`

And for the inside `<div class="mydiv">` style with `position: absolute; left: 0;` or `left: 50%`.

Answer (score 0):

The main point is positioning:

`position: fixed;` will position the div relative to the browser window 
`position: relative;` will position it relative to its normal position 
`position: absolute;` will position it relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static (so it is not really absolute after all)

check http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with positions like relative and absolute.
You just need one top parent above all div.
I have created following example. It will help you to achieve what you need.

```
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dhavalsolanki/tjv5e1tn/)
```